# How to make UIView like UILabel to scretch and shrink depending on the amount of texts or content in it?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uilabel

If we put too much text, `UILabel` would shrink the texts.

Sometimes we put 4 lines in a text. Sometimes there are 20 lines in a text. Sometimes there are none.

Also text may be short or long.

How to make `UILabel` to fit the amount of that texts?

Also how to to make `UIView` that encompass that `UILabel` to also fit the larger or smaller `UILabel`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [UIKit Additions to NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) to determine the size of a text with a given font.

```
NSString *myLongText = @"......" // some long text.
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
CGSize size = [myLongText sizeWithFont:font 
                              forWidth:maxWidth
                         lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
myLabel.frame = (CGRect){myLabel.frame.origin, size};
```